# Library for decoding a zip file in chunk

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios

Hi fellow overflowers,
i need to decode a large zip file (around 20mb) on the ipad. Is there a way to parse the zip file in chunks? 
Ideally i would like to pass the decoder (let's say) 512k of data at time, and get back a chunk of decoded data, because i have a feeling that loading all the file in memory and then decompress it could lead to severe memory problems. 
A pointer to some incremental decoding libraries would be nice!

Thanks, 
Giuliano

**UPDATE**: the link provided by Matt in his answer worked fine for me ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried objective-zip? http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/

There's an example near the bottom of http://code.google.com/p/objective-zip/wiki/GettingStarted, showing how to read big files.

Comment: The links in this answer are no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I have achieve unzipping files using GCD. This examples uses unzipping of files in different thread and when done it notifies main thread and main thread updates the information.... Hope this may also be solution to your problem....

http://www.raywenderlich.com/4295/multithreading-and-grand-central-dispatch-on-ios-for-beginners-tutorial